# jQuery move node out of its parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, prepend

I have this code:

```
<ul class="list">
  <li>
    <a href="#" >
      <img src="IMAGE" />
      SOME TEXT
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" >
      <img src="ANOTHER IMAGE" />
      SOME DIFFERENT TEXT
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want the images prepended to the parent node like this:

```
<ul class="list">
  <li>
    <img src="IMAGE" />
    <a href="#" >
      SOME TEXT
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="ANOTHER IMAGE" />
    <a href="#" >
      SOME DIFFERENT TEXT
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: any particular event should be triggered when the append happens? ... have you already attempted any JS code?

Comment: Not sure what you are wanting to do... Are you adding the `img` tags with jQuery after the rest of the code shown in your example is already in the DOM?

Comment: How this image will come ? Some kind of trigger/ajax ?

Comment: there is no trigger needed, when the dom is ready it should be detached and append immediately after the li tag like in my example,.. 

and yes i already tried some code but its a little bit complicated so ive choosen this simple code example

Comment: Well in that case the answer @Alnitak has given you should be perfect.

Comment: totally agree with ElGabbu please try first Google then post your question and make your questions clear

Comment: @user64837 sorry 'bout that but dont you think that even more examples in web help more people in future?

Comment: @YeppThat'sMe don't worry about them, I doubt it would be at all easy to find the answer you needed on Google.

Comment: sorry if you got offended dear...meant just try before you post!!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.list > li > a > img').each(function() {
    $(this).insertBefore($(this).parent());
})
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/3nEVz/

**EDIT** I came up with a cleaner version:

```
$('.list > li > a > img').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().before(this);
})
```

Comment: yeah, I just revised to change that while you were commenting

Comment: nb: I've gone this route rather than simply prepend to the `<li>` since it explicitly moves the "img" before the "a", regardless of any other elements that might be present.

Comment: oh GREAT,.. it works perfectly even in my complicated case :) BIIIG thanks :)

Comment: @Alnitak: Good point and worthwhile clarification. Depends whether the OP's objective is to keep the `img` with the `a` or have it as the first element in the `li`.

Comment: @Luke well the title was "append to parent", so I figured keeping it with the `a` was the right thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('ul.list img').each(function(_, elem) {
    var $elem = $(elem);
    $elem.prependTo( $elem.closest('li') );
});
```

**demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/hPbZD/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('ul.list > li > a > img').each(function() {
      $(this).closest('li').prepend(this);
    });
});
```

See it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mL3cY/).