# Js - A more elegant / efficiant way of finding nth element in DOM than if-else

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, move

I need to move an element one level up in dom ...

So I made :

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery('.pricing-table .fancy-header').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).parent().before(this);
        })  

 });
```

and Also this is ok ..

```
var $node = jQUery('.pricing-table .fancy-header');
           jQuery($node).parent().before($node);
     })
```

And it works great ( http://jsfiddle.net/obmerk99/EdvTz/ ) , my problem is , that on some specific page loads, I might have 2 different `.fancy-header` elements and I need to move the first one UP and the second one DOWN ..

See Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/obmerk99/EdvTz/3/

Now , apart from some probable syntax mistake that makes it fail ( but that I can probably manage ) , my question is more about finding a more elegant `and/or` efficient way of doing so than a primitive `if-else` statement .

Is there such a way in jQuery ?

Comment: You start by asking for "efficient", but end by asking for "elegant". Which one are you ultimately after?

Comment: @BlueSkies Well, since semantic is so important ,and you have indeed caught that -  than seeing BOTH and the differences between them would be great. edited accordingly .

Comment: what you have is about as clean as you can get http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383941/jquery-move-node-out-of-its-parent

Comment: @Eru - Thanks - but I was referring more to the `if-else` statement .

Comment: @ObmerkKronen: FYI, you can add a `$` (or any valid name you want) as a parameter to the `.ready()` callback, and safely use it inside the callback as a reference to `jQuery`.

Comment: @BlueSkies - That I know . But this code goes inside wordpress, which is notorious for not wanting to parse the `$` under some conditions ( it loads in safe mode i think )... I am just  used to write the whole `jQUery` reference :-) But thanks again ..

Comment: Ah, yeah I think I remember hearing that they use an old version.

Comment: Nop - now it is the new(est ?? ) . But I was developing WP since 1.5 . So I am just used to automatically write the whole name. I was not even aware that that "problem" is fixed in newer jQuery versions as opposed to the old ones :-) How much can one learn :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Elegant" is subjective, but here's a short approach anyway.

```
jQuery('.pricing-table .fancy-header').each(function (i) {
    jQuery(this).parent()[i ? "after" : "before"](this);
});
```

Since you'll only have one or two matches, we just use the counter to select either the `"after"` (if `1`) or `"before"` (if `0`) method.

---

But for clarity, an `if` statement may be better. You can still use the `i` counter.

```
jQuery('.pricing-table .fancy-header').each(function (i) {
    if (i)
        jQuery(this).parent().after(this);
    else
        jQuery(this).parent().before(this);
});
```

---

And here's efficient if that really matters (guessing not):

```
jQuery('.pricing-table .fancy-header').each(function (i) {
    var par = this.parentNode;
    par.insertBefore(this, i ? par.nextSibling : par);
});
```

Comment: I might also have `zero` or `NO` element

Comment: +1, but this code needs a source code comment to communicate its intent.

Comment: @ObmerkKronen: If there are no matches, then the `.each()` callback never runs.

Comment: Ok . The first method ( "Elegant" ) I understand - and it is really great ! . The second however , is beyond my understanding ( both code, and as for it´s "efficiency" ) :-)

Comment: @Blue Skies - +1 .. I was too fast to comment.

Comment: @ObmerkKronen: The second one is using the native DOM API instead of jQuery. As such, it'll run much faster, but for this purpose, you'll never notice.

Comment: Great . simple ternary operator. Now I know how to implement in jQuery ( I always only use it in PHP ) .Thanks again..

Comment: For the efficient method, if you wanted to improve it even more, you'd lose the `$().each` and use a for loop as this [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/browser-diet-jquery-each-vs-for-loop) shows would be faster.

Comment: @ObmerkKronen - Edited =D