# Move a div before its parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to take a div (in this case "childDiv2") and its contents and move it before its parent.

So essentially take this

```
<div id="parentDiv">
   <div class="childDiv1">
     <div class="contents"></div>
     <div class="contents"></div>
     <div class="contents"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="childDiv2">
     <div class="contents"></div>
     <div class="contents"></div>
     <div class="contents"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and make it this

```
<div class="childDiv2">
  <div class="contents"></div>
  <div class="contents"></div>
  <div class="contents"></div>
</div>
<div id="parentDiv">
   <div class="childDiv1">
     <div class="contents"></div>
     <div class="contents"></div>
     <div class="contents"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I know I probably need to use .parent() and .before() to get it to work, but I'm stuck on how the jquery would look. Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at this 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383941/jquery-move-node-out-of-its-parent][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383941/jquery-move-node-out-of-its-parent

Comment: I looked at that, I only asked the question because the .each() confused me alittle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use the [`.insertBefore()` method](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/):

```
$('#parentDiv .childDiv2').insertBefore('#parentDiv');
```