# Jquery to get rid of html tags that come up as regular text

Tags: jquery, html

I've seen my question around but I may have worded it wrong, but here's my issue. For some reason my code comes up with p tags inside of a p tag already so it looks like this:

```
 <p class="SubPromoTitle"><p>Pentair IntelliFlo 2 VST Variable Speed, 15% off!</p></p>
```

So people are seeing those tags before and after the text. I just need a jquery to get rid of it, doesn't have to be all non-text elements, it's just the extra p tags that I need to be removed.

Comment: `I just need a jquery`, this is not how this side works. Show us what you have tried and specify the problem that you encountered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery move node out of its parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383941/jquery-move-node-out-of-its-parent)

Answer (score 1):

This is solution using jquery:

This selects all `<p>` elements, then uses `.contents()` to target the text content of the `<p>`, then `.unwrap()` to remove its `parent` element.

```js
$('p').each(function(item){
  $(this).contents().unwrap();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="SubPromoTitle">
<p>Pentair IntelliFlo 2 VST Variable Speed, 15% off!
</p>
</p>
```