# How to wrap an input element and its label into a div and place it after its parent element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm writing a Django form with an `ImageField`, which by default has a [`ClearableFileInput`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/widgets/#clearablefileinput) widget which inserts an additional checkbox to clear the file if one is already selected.

I'm implementing the form using Materialize (http://materializecss.com/forms.html), by which the file `<input>` is wrapped in a `div` with class `"btn"`. In the case that a file is already uploaded, however, the additional 'clear' checkbox also appears inside the button, whereas I'd like to have it outside.

So far, I've tried calling [`wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/) on the selected elements and then following the approach described in [jQuery move node out of its parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383941/jquery-move-node-out-of-its-parent):

```js
    $("input[id*='-clear_id']").add("label[for*='-clear_id']").wrapAll("<div />").each(function() {
      $(this).parent().after(this);
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">  
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="file-field input-field col s12">
      <label class="active" for="id_headshot">Headshot</label>
      <div class="btn">
        <span>File</span>
        Currently: <a href="https://lucy-dev2.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/IMG_3515.png">IMG_3515.png</a>
<input type="checkbox" name="headshot-clear" id="headshot-clear_id" />
<label for="headshot-clear_id">Clear</label><br />
Change:
<input type="file" name="headshot" id="id_headshot" />
        
      </div>
      <div class="file-path-wrapper">
        <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

However, what I'm getting is an empty `div` element after the parent, followed by the selected `input` and `label` elements:

[image]

How can I get the `input` and `label` to first get wrapped inside a `div`, and then have that `div` moved after its parent `div`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the wrap a class so it's easier to handle, then use that new class as a selector with **[`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/)** method.

### Demo

```js
$(":checkbox, :checkbox + label").wrapAll("<div class='wrap'></div>");   

$('.wrap').insertAfter('.btn');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">  
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="file-field input-field col s12">
      <label class="active" for="id_headshot">Headshot</label>
      <div class="btn">
        <span>File</span>
        Currently: <a href="https://lucy-dev2.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/IMG_3515.png">IMG_3515.png</a>
<input type="checkbox" name="headshot-clear" id="headshot-clear_id" />
<label for="headshot-clear_id">Clear</label><br />
Change:
<input type="file" name="headshot" id="id_headshot" />
        
      </div>
      <div class="file-path-wrapper">
        <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: this does not wrap the `label` along with the input field

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam use devtools (F12) and look inside of `<div class='wrap'>`

Comment: i was watching the first one :D